# HTML/JS - Let user paste image URL as background

Tags: javascript, html

I have something that I would like to do, but I am not sure that it is possible.

I want a text box (input), and when a user pastes a URL of an image (Say, their facebook profile pic), it will take that URL and set it as the background image URL on the website.

Is this possible? Could someone write up a code? It seems like if it is possible, it shouldn't be too difficult..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's definitely possible and it's not that hard either. Have you tried something yet? Because this sounds like "please do my work"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changebackground(){
    var url = document.getElementById('bgchanger').value;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + url + "')";
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="bgchanger" value="Enter a background URL" />
<input type="button" onclick="changebackground();" value="Change!" />
```

Untested but should be ok.

**Edit** Tested and works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/EK3Y3/

Comment: You sir, are amazing! EDIT: If you saw what I had before, never mind, got it! Again, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use jQuery to achieve this easily, although you can use javascript as well.

Here's an example. http://jsfiddle.net/FvDWw/

Paste a valid image url in that textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by attaching a handler to the "change" event of an input element.  Then use the value of the input element to update the "background-image" property of the "body" element's css.

For example, http://jsfiddle.net/aB3sg/